# pause for the Event Dispatcher

Tags: java, swing

I've got a (primarily) single threaded application which updates a swing chart component (jfreechart) as it goes.

since all updates to the chart are done on the event dispatching thread, the que of tasks is getting too large and the chart is not updating in time with the code that is updating it.

is there a way to pause every so often so that the event dispatching thread can catch up?

my first inclination would be to que a dummy task via [`SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29)... could it be as simple as that?

cheers, p.

Comment: yes that seems to work, anyone have a tidier method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dummy task would work, but maybe you could consider skipping some updates in the data-generating thread.

It depends on exactly what you are doing. Is your goal to compute something as fast as possible and update the GUI along the way, or are you trying to create a nice GUI that demonstrates some data analysis?

If it's the former then you really don't want to block waiting for the GUI to update - it will just slow down your computation. In that case just skip some updates and coalesce them into less frequent, larger updates.

If it's the latter then `invokeAndWait` will probably do the trick.

Comment: i'm re-using some code that is designed for a less intensive process and the goal is just to visualise the real-time information when it's read back at a faster than real-time rate. it doesn't need to be super fast, but i would like the process and the ED to keep up with each other. so looks like invokeAndWait. i'll see if someone comes up with something better, or i'll give you a tick in a day or 2. cheers.

Comment: You could always do all your updates inside an `invokeAndwait` - then you can guarantee your read thread and the EDT will run in lock-step. Repaints may still be coalesced, however.

Comment: you're right, however that would mean i would need to change the shared code (which i don't want to do) and it would run much slower than the single `invokeAndWait` at (much fewer) key points in the process.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to decouple the update rates: update the data model asynchronously and update the view at a lower, adjustable rate. This [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/threadwatch) uses [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to effect periodic updates, but a fixed ratio is an alternative. In the case of `JFreeChart`, the `fireSeriesChanged()` method of [`DynamicTimeSeriesCollection`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/DynamicTimeSeriesCollection.html) should give you necessary control.